# Database Design: Store Credit Card Information

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

Ok so far I have a table which stores receipt information.

For example:

```
TABLE receipt
receipt_ID (int)(primary key)
creditcard (int) //Last 4 digits of credit card.
purhcaseAmount (int)
transactionTypeID (int)
remainingBalance (int)
```

The creditCard column has a restriction of 4 digits because most receipts only show the last 4 digits of the credit card number.

However, some banks show the first 2 digits and the last 2 digits and I want to retain this information into the database.

How would you modify your database design to fit this business requirement?

Comment: Be very careful with credit card info.  Even partials can be considered in scope for PCI compliance.

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but certainly you could make it a varchar and put a character flag before the 4 digits. So for last 4 digits it would be l9999 and for first and last two b9999 or whatever characters you want. Just the first idea I had.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to store multiple pieces of information about the credit card, such as name, card type, etc. For the number itself, why be clever? Just make it a `varchar(19)` and store it as `12****************34` or whatever other format you choose.

Comment: I would worry about a column that would allow you to accidentally put a full credit card number in.

Comment: @podiluska true, there is a theoretical 19-digit card out there.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs you could "accidentally" store a full credit card number in any field large enough. The shape of the field alone is not a security risk.

Comment: @RexM, having a field large enough to hold a full credit card number can imply to the next developer looking at the code that credit card numbers are supposed to go in that column.  Besides, why store nonsignificant information?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use an int, even for the last 4 digits. As a rule of thumb, if the number you're storing makes no sense if it is added up, store it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If your business requirement is to store the 4 digits, does it matter where they are in the string?  What will this information be used for?

If it doesn't matter, just grab the digits with a regular expression, ignore the stuff that isn't a digit, and stuff the digits into your table column.